# ImportError: cannot import name 'audio'

Tags: tensorflow, error-handling

When trying to import the gpu tensorflow It doesnt work as planned. It gives me an error. 
This is the error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C: \ Users \ BeMore \ Anaconda3 \ lib \ site-packages \ tensorflow \ __ init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v1 import audio
ImportError: can not import name 'audio'
```

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\BeMore\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v1 import audio
ImportError: cannot import name 'audio'
```

Comment: What's your question ?

Answer (score 0):

In Python an `ImportError` is raised when an *import statement has trouble successfully importing the specified module*. From your stack trace message we can see that it **failed on line 31** within the `__init__.py` file for tensorflow when it tried to run this import: `from tensorflow._api.v1 import audio`. This is the relevant section of your stack trace:

> tensorflow__init__.py", line 31, in from tensorflow._api.v1 import audio ImportError: cannot import name 'audio',

So it was unable to find the `audio` module, since tensorflow is a 3rd party module that you're downloading this `ImportError` is probably due to not installing a necessary dependency. Maybe you could try installing the relevant libraries again with a:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

From your stack trace I also see you're using `Python3` with `Anaconda` as your package manager on a Windows machine. According to tensorflow's documentation both `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` are supported on Windows.

"*tensorflow — Latest stable release for CPU-only (Ubuntu and Windows)

tensorflow-gpu — Latest stable release with GPU support (Ubuntu and Windows)"*

For more information click [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: np @edtech, If my answer helped you please consider accepting it :)